# Is it possible to intervene if a task fails?

Tags: hadoop

I have a mapreduce job running on many urls and parsing them.
I need way to handle a scenario in which one parsing task crashes on a fatal error like OOM error.
In the normal hadoop behaivour a task is retried for a defined number of time and than the job fails.
the problem is with urls that are corrupted in some way causing this error. These urls will fail in all the retries.

Is there a way to intervene after a task fails? or after the number of retries is reached? and prevent the whole job from failing?